# Group by in Python Pandas (Multiple columns join with , )

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table in CSV just like this:

[Base CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsah3.png)

And i need to group it just like this:

In all my `CONCURSO` only `CIDADE` and `UF` change.

[Expectd CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILUPR.png)

i'm trying this code but it doesn't work.

Can you guys help me, please?

```
import...

    new_df = pd.read_csv(fr'C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Anon\data\swamp\{date}\nao_tratado.csv')
    new_df = new_df.groupby(by=['Concurso'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df]).to_csv(fr'C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Anon\data\lake\{date}\tratado.csv', index=False)
    print('We are done.')
```

Comment: So between all your `Concurso`, only `Cidade` and `UF` change?

Comment: Yes, only those two columns change. `CONCURSO` need to be agrupated in one line, `UF` and  `CIDADE` need to be nested in one cell with comas separateding the values.

Answer (score 0):

The `agg()` method of Pandas can take a dictionary for the `func` parameter. This dict maps the column and its aggregation function.

I guess you can then do the following:

```py
columns_to_aggregate = ["Cidade", "UF"]
columns_for_groupby = ["Concurso"]
columns = list(set(new_df.columns).difference(columns_for_groupby))
aggregation_func = {c: (lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x))) if c in columns_to_aggregate else "min" for c in columns}
new_df = new_df.groupby(by=columns_for_groupby, as_index=False).agg(aggregation_func)
new_df.to_csv(fr'C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Anon\data\lake\{date}\tratado.csv', index=False)
```

Tell me if it does not work :)

Comment: This code almost worked... All `Cidade` become 0 and `UF` is not separated by comas.

Comment: Try the new one! I just changed a little bit the aggregation_func.

Comment: We got 2 erros. The first one: `line 61, in <module>
    new_df = new_df.groupby(by=columns_for_groupby, as_index=False).agg(aggregation_func)` The second: `line 60, in <lambda>
    aggregation_func = {c: (lambda x: ", ".join(x)) if c in columns_to_aggregate else "min" for c in columns}` Output error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: The code have changed the order of the columns, and all empty cells become NaN, but it worked! :3

Comment: You can then easily post-process the groupby to make the Nan cells as you want and re-order the dataset!

Comment: I am running the code again and I realized that it is creating other columns and grouping some values, such as;'Concurso,Ganhadores_Quina,Valor_Acumulado,1ª Dezena,Cidade,Arrecadacao_Total,5ª Dezena,Data Sorteio,Acumulado,2ª Dezena ,4ª Dezena,6ª Dezena'

Comment: What do you mean it creates new columns? What are the names of the new columns? what values do they contain?